# CEK machine vs SECD machine

Tags: lambda-calculus, computation-models, performance, operational-semantics

What are the differences between the [CEK machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CEK_Machine) and the [modern variant](https://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/%7Erobin/class/521/lectures_lambda/secd.pdf) of the [SECD machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SECD_machine) (which combines stack and dump) from the point of view of performance, memory efficiency, and other factors? Are there any papers that explicitly compare the two?